# operating on props in vue.js components

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

Im pretty newm to vue and i'm trying to migrate the frontend of my laravel project to vue but i'm having an issue with it, i'm trying to loop through an array of provided objects called rooms and create divs for each of the in my component as well as setting the default room_id as the first id of the room. The problem is when is access the provided prop array called 'room' in the dom (html) it works flawlessly, but in my vue code for the component file it always seems to be undefined or empty
Here is my components vue code:

```
export default {
    created() {
        //this.loadMessages(this.room_id)
        console.log(this.first_room)  //undefined;
        console.log(this.rooms) //empty array;
    },
    props: ['rooms','first_room'],
    computes:{
        myrooms: function(){
            return this.first_room;
        }
    },
    data()
    {
        return{
            messages: [],
            newMessage: '',
            room_id: 1 //for test purposes, this works,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadMessages(id)
        {
            axios.get('/messages/'+id).then(response => {
                this.messages = response.data;
                console.log(response.data);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

the important part of the component html

```
<div v-for="room in rooms">
    <div class="chat-user room">
        <div v-for="other in room.others">
            <img class="chat-avatar img-circle" :src="other.image" alt="image" >                                        
            <div class="chat-user-name">
                <a :href="'/user/' + other.id">{{ other.name}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
//this all works, just for reference
```

method where i set the values passed to the prop in my main vue instance

**EDIT: THE PARENT INSTANCE CODE**
Oh and i cant seem too access the rooms array being passed as it is always empty IN code but it loops in the html

```
window.App.app= new Vue({
el: '#wrapper',
data: {
    messages: [],
    rooms: [],
    test: 'yes',
    first: ''
},
created() {
    this.fetchRooms();
    this.first = 1;
},
methods: {
    fetchMessages(id) {
        console.log(id);
    },
    fetchRooms()
    {
        axios.get('/rooms').then(response => {
            this.rooms = response.data;
        });
    }
}
});
```

finally where i call my component

```
<chat-messages :rooms="rooms" :first_room="1"></chat-messages>
//variables referenced from main vue instance
```

I have literally torn most of my hair on this, please any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you also add the `vue-instance` code of the parent component?

Comment: It's not `computes`, It should be `computed`

Comment: Ok @BelminBedak ill try that thanks

Comment: `data` doesn't seem to contain `messages`, `rooms`? is that intentional?

Comment: It was an error copying the code to stack overflow i've fixed that

Comment: @BelminBedak changing it to computed solved the first_room(a number) being passed, i was able to set a local computed variable to first_room, but if i set anything to the rooms array, it is still empty?

Comment: @carrion try using a `watch` on `rooms` in your child component. I think it is an empty array because when the child component gets created the api call didn't get resolved, leading to the default value it had on the parent which is `[]`

Comment: thanks @AmreshVenugopal can you expatiate on that, i'm still pretty new to vue, should the watcher be on the parent or component instance?

Comment: @carrion I have added code and explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the child component to which the props are passed on.

```
export default {
  created() {
    console.log(this.first_room)  //undefined;
  },
  props: ['rooms','first_room'],
  computed :{
    myrooms: function(){
        return this.first_room;
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
        messages: [],
        newMessage: '',
        room_id: 1 //for test purposes, this works,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    rooms (n, o) {
      console.log(n, o) // n is the new value, o is the old value.
    }
  },
  methods: {
    loadMessages (id) {
        axios.get('/messages/'+id).then(response => {
            this.messages = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        });
    }
  }
}
```

You can add a watch on data properties or computed to see the change in their values.

In the question, (as what it appears to be the case), you have `console`d the value of the props in the `created` lifecycle, the props' value gets changed by an API call in the parent component, after the creation of the child component. That explains why your template shows the data but not in the `console` in the created lifecycle hook.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot solved my problem, as you said, when the rooms were first logged in created() it was empty but when they were logged in watch it contained all values, again thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped :)